# A new public key was added to your account

Tags: git, github

Мне на почту пришло письмо "A new public key was added to your account. The following SSH key was added to your account:".

Я авторизован на гитхабе с двух компьютеров (оба дома) и в настройках увидел два ssh-ключа. Об одном из них упоминалось в письме. Я его удалил, но через несколько минут пришло письмо, что снова был сгенерирован новый ssh-ключ.

Не пойму, это гитхаб автоматический старый ключ перегенерировал, или мой аккаунт кто-то взломал? У меня стоит двухэтапная авторизация и никаких смс с кодом не приходило

Comment: у вас запущен GitHub клиент для Windows?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Я каждый день его на одном из компьютеров запускаю, чтобы коммит сделать. А на втором раз в неделю где-то. Но когда письмо пришло, ничего запущено не было

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что аккаунт взломали, сам GitHub никакие ключи не добавляет.

Я бы посоветовал посмотреть список авторизованных приложений, возможно атака идёт через них: `Settings -> Authorized applications`.

Comment: Там только GitHub for Windows и Stack Overflow Careers. Очень странно

Answer (score 2):

На [этой странице](https://github.com/settings/security) в разделе `Security History` вы можете посмотреть события типа `public_key.create`. При щелчке на заголовок события появится всплывающее окно с подробной информацией:

[image: security history]

Comment: Там написано, что для этого ключа, о котором было письмо, сначала произошло событие `public_key.delete`, потом `public_key.verify`, а потом `public_key.create`. В полях из вашего скриншота указаны мои данные, включая ip. Но я ничего не менял. И когда удалил этот ключ, то поменял пароль, а потом ключ опять сам собой сгенерировался. Я его опять удалил и пока ничего не происходило

Comment: Запустил клиент гитхаба, опять сгенерился ключ. Ну вроде причина во мне, только непонятно, почему он в первый раз сам по себе сгенерировался